# Conversion between InputStream and BufferedImage

Tags: java, image-manipulation

I want to convert an InputStream object representing an image file to a BufferedImage object and after performing some operations on the BufferedImage convert it back to an InputStream so that it can be written to disk.I dont want to create a file object on disk first in order to prevent additional IO overhead.

I think i can do the following to convert a BufferedImage to InputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image,fileExtension, outputStream);
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

Is that correct ?. Also, i have the following two questions

1. How to get BufferedImage object from an InputStream object
2. Can i get the filesize directly from the InputStream object ?

Some example would really help

Thank You

Comment: "convert it back to an InputStream so that it can be written to disk" why do you want to convert it to a InputStream if you want to write it to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look at the `read(InputStream stream)` method of [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html)
2. No, you can have a peek using `available()` but this does not guarantee the size of the stream (it works for `FileInputStream`)
3. You can't write to an input stream (as its name states it, it is an input, not an output). To write, you need an `OutputStream` and you can use the `write(RenderedImage im, String formatName, OutputStream output)` of ImageIO